# Getting specific item with findRecord

Tags: ember.js

I'm new at ember and as first app I'm trying to build a little online shop.
I can receive "all products" as product overview but not one specific product by id.

I have following in the router.js:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('products');
  this.route('product', {path: 'products/:product_id'});
});
```

My products.js (which works):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return this.get('store').query('product', {});
  }
});
```

And the product.js (which does generate the problem):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params){
    return this.store.findRecord('product', params.product_id);
  }
});
```

The project is available under https://github.com/hatchling-shop/hatchling/tree/master/EmberHatchling

Comment: You basically want to swap your query for a `findAll` if you are passing an empty object, as of the `findRecord` it looks fine, are you getting any error messages? Is there a network request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running the code seems that you have an issue in the API in `Product.findById()` and not in Ember.

In the following method:

```
Product.findById(id, function(id, err, product) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.json({product: product});
});
```

the params in the callback are wrong, instead you need to remove `id` and change to:

```
Product.findById(id, function(err, product) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.json({product: product});
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: wow, this solved my problem! How did you get to the solution? I searched almost an entire day.